# how to start to write an SDK for php MVC self created framework

Tags: php, api, rest, sdk

I don't know how to actually ask my question ,but here it comes:

My boss wanted me to create a simple MVC with PHP for our online-shopping website 
, I did it ( watching youtube and ...) , it's very simple and easily made .

Now he keeps asking me to :

**First** Create a RESTful API ( that uses curl ).

**Second** Create a well documented SDK !!.

I've searched a lot (really ) , right know I can understand what an API does 
but I'm not sure what's SDK  and how to start to write the code

Can someone give me a line of code of example of how to start to write ?

What he means by **well documented ** ?

I've searched in google and I know what are SDK and API literally mean, but my problem is I can't make a relation between my MVC and API and SDK .

How can I start to write an API ?

Where should I begin ?

What's the point ?

Can someone give me an example ?

What my SDK supposed to do ?

I've seen lots of videos about API , all of them talks about using REST and REST is very good and we should us GET/POST/DELETE/PUT and  so on and so force .

but where should I start ?

**EDIT**

In my case , an online-shopping which simply searchs through our MongoDB database and returns new products and some other simple tasks , how should I use RESTful API ?  or SKD ?

Thanks and  please tell me if the explanation is not understandable .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have a task ahead of you.

## Restful Routing

Restful routing is a way of communicating with a server via the standard `HTTP protocols`.  These are things like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc...

When routing in a restful way, you do not need to call ambiguous methods to retrieve, update, or delete data on the server.

For example, when attempting to retrieve the users from a server, you might have make a call to `http://domain.tld/getAllUsers.php`.  This is not restful.

However, if you retrieve all users by making a call to `http://domain.tld/users/` and specify that you want to access this call via `GET`, which is built in to the `HTTP protocol`, this will be `restful`.

There are many resources online about learning more about `restful routing`.

## APIs

`APIs` are `Application Programming Interafaces`.  For instance, when you are using `restful routing` to structure your application, you are also implementing an `API`, because you are giving others a way to access data on your server.

However, all `APIs` are not `restful`.  In fact, many are not, and these are more difficult for `application programmers` to learn because they do not follow a `standard`.

There have been many books written about `APIs` and it is more than I can cover in this response.  A book that I would recommend is `Build APIs You Won't Hate` by Phil Sturgeon.

## SDKs

`SDKs` are `Software Development Kits` and while most of the time they are very extensive, the `restful API` that you will be developing will constitute an `SDK`.

This might not be what your boss wants though, that is something you will have to ask him.

## Documentation

Well documented code is easy to read and easy to understand.  This will require a very good grasp of the language your target audience uses.

***The first step in writing good documentation is writing well commented code.***  Having well commented code is the best documentation you can have and after it is written, you can use a tool such as `PHPDoc` to generate documentation for you.  This generation might not be as extensive as you would like, and that only means that you need more comments.

## Some Recommendations

***Read through code from other developers*** that have implemented things you are seeking.  I am biased in this instance because it is my current framework of choice, but [`Laravel`](http://laravel.com) is a `PHP MVC framework` that does all of this very well.  The code is also well documented and easy to understand.

In addition, there are a lot of well written packages on [`Packagist`](http://packagist.org) that might be of help to you, you should check them out and look into [`Composer`](http://getcomposer.org) if you haven't already.

*If anyone reading this finds mistakes please correct me.*

Comment: like I said , I've read a lot , but I simply dont know where to begin ?

Comment: This was a good answer , thanks , but I'm now sure about your explanation of SDK 
you said I'm supposed to ask my boss to give me an SDK ? 
what do you mean by that?

Comment: There are a lot of example REST API classes you can use to help get you started.

Comment: @ChrisG , could you please give me some ?

Comment: Give this a read - http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/